# UIScrollview framerate issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a pretty big uiscrollview (1700p) which contains a uiimageview as the background, 2 uitableviews and at the bottom there are 5 uibuttons 1uisegmentedbutton and 3 uitextfields.

scrolling past the uitableview is fine but once the buttons enter the screen the framerate gets very laggy. I used instruments to remove all leaks.  Is this too big or a uiscrollview or does my problem lie elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answers, doesn't surprise me due to my lack info in the question but it was because I was rounding the corners of some of te subviews in the scrollview.  This slows down framerate.